# How to disable QuickEdit Mode with Python

Tags: python-3.x, windows-10

I am trying to make a function that simply disables QuickEdit Mode in the python console. Here is what I have:

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import wintypes

def disable_quick_edit_mode():
    kernel32 = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32')
    dword_for_std_input_handle = ctypes.wintypes.DWORD(-10)
    dword_for_enable_extended_flags = ctypes.wintypes.DWORD(0x0080)
    std_input_handle = kernel32.GetStdHandle(dword_for_std_input_handle)
    kernel32.SetConsoleMode(std_input_handle, dword_for_enable_extended_flags)
    last_error = kernel32.GetLastError()
    return last_error
```

This returns error code 6 (ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I just realized that this code works fine as long as stdin is not being redirected, as is probably the case when running from an IDE. I tried running the .py from Windows Explorer with a 10 second sleep and everything appears operational.